# Tabla de Auditoria al momento de hacer clic en enlace href

Tags: php

Necesito generar una tabla de auditoria que se ejecute al momento de hacer click en un enlace href. ¿Cual seria la mejor forma de hacerlo?

Comment: Una tabla no se ejecuta. Se ejecutan operaciones sobre ella. En cuanto a cómo hacerlo, depende. El `<a>` redirije directamente a otra pagina o se modifica su comportamiento vía JS? En el primer caso, añadiendo una consulta en la pagina de destino lo tendrías resuelto. En el segundo caso (que no redirija), tal vez debas usar alguna forma asíncronica, como AJAX o AXIOS, etc.

Comment: La idea es insertar datos en una tabla antes de que se redirija a la pagina. Pensaba usar una funcion con el evento onclick pero no se si sea lo mas recomendable.

Comment: Por qué motivo antes y no en la página de destino?

Comment: porque la pagina destino es variable y en algunos casos no es manejable. Se quiere capturar el usuario y la fecha en una tabla en sql server pero el unico evento que se tiene es el clic sobre el hipervinculo.

Comment: Yo no sé mucho de javascript y siempre prefiero evitarlo. Las veces que me encontré en situaciones similares, creé un archivo intermedio de PHP desde donde se manejaban esa clase de operaciones.

Comment: se entiende pero en una situación como esta donde el link esta en un href que se ejecuta si o si y el único momento de captura es haciendo clic sobre ese enlace, ¿se puede usar una funcion javascript como intermediario para que una pagina php ejecute el insert antes de que se redireccione al link original?

Comment: Si, se puede. Yo no sé cómo hacerlo conforme a los estándares actuales así voy a dejar que alguien que sepa responda. Me pregunto: Si podes modificar la pagina para añadirle el javascript, por qué no cambiar el `href`, añadir el enlace de destino (de la forma que sea, se me ocurren un par) y en el archivo intermedio de PHP que procesa esas operaciones redirijir a la url de destino original?

Comment: Tambien pense cambiar el href pero el dilema es el mismo, que se debe ejecutar al momento de hacer click sobre el y de momento no se como hacerlo de otra forma.

Comment: SI, entiendo. Aunque la acción se va a ejecutar en el destino. En el archivo intermedio o proxy de PHP, se puede ejecutar la consulta y, en caso de error, volver al origen, y en caso de éxito continuar al destino. Qué clase de página es el origen? Es un formulario?

Comment: Es un formulario que dada la característica del pedido te lanza una o varias urls internas o externas. Al hacer click en esa url es cuando se requiere que se capture el usuario y la fecha, ademas de otros datos. Todo los datos están identificados, solo falta ver como insertarlos en una tabla en ese momento.

Answer (score 0):

Por favor, completa tu pregunta con la información que proporcionas en los comentarios y el intento que hayas hecho para conseguirlo.

Entretanto, te adelanto esta posible solución:

```
<?php   // api en PHP
    if(isset($_GET['auditoria'])){
        $conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','_so');
        $conn->query("
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS auditoria(
              id_auditoria int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
              instante datetime
              );        
        ");
        $conn->query("
            INSERT INTO auditoria (instante) VALUES (NOW());        
        ");
        echo json_encode($conn->query("
            SELECT * FROM auditoria;
        ")->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
        exit();
    }
?>

<script>    // función asíncrona en JS
    async function api(){
        url='?auditoria=1';
        let r = await (await fetch(url,{mode:"no-cors"})).json();
        console.log(r);
        document.getElementById('auditorias').innerHTML =  JSON.stringify(r);
    }
</script>

<form>
    <input name="test1" autofocus/>
    <a href="#" onclick="api()">click</a>
    <button>TEST</button>
</form>

<div id="auditorias" style="padding:30px;"></div>

<?php

echo 'Página recargada por última vez a las '.date('H:i:s');
```